# Save pointer address to dereferenced pointer / own malloc function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm stuck, maybe on a very simple question.

In university we have to make our own malloc-function in C. I only have a problem when saving the pointer Address on the dereferenced pointer. Im working on heap and there is enough memory left.

```
void *actual_pointer = sbrk(sizeof(Node));
*(char*)actual_pointer = 'O';
actual_pointer = actual_pointer+sizeof(char);
*(char*)actual_pointer = 'K';
actual_pointer = actual_pointer+sizeof(unsigned int);
*(unsigned int*)actual_pointer = size;
actual_pointer = actual_pointer+sizeof(unsigned int);
*(unsigned int*)actual_pointer = 0;
actual_pointer = actual_pointer+sizeof(unsigned int);
*actual_pointer = actual_pointer;
```

The last line doesn't work. I tried everything. Isn't it possible to store some pointer Address to the dereferenced pointer?

```
typedef struct _Node_ 
{
  char checkCorruption_[2];
  unsigned int size_;
  unsigned int status_;
  char *location_;
  struct Node *next_;
  struct Node *prev_;
} Node;
```

This is the structure of my double-linked list representing the momory structure.

My Idea was the following:
We need to make a simple mallocfunction. From main function for example `data[1] = malloc(100 * sizeof(int))` is called. Then I will create in the mallocfunction one Node and store the "checkCorruption"-Value 'OK' in it. After it the size, in my example "100 * sizeof(int)". After this I store a 0 for used or a 1 for free in it. Then I will store the location which is returned to data[0] - the storage gets reserved with `sbrk(100*sizeof(int))` and begins at the location. Then i will store the Pointer to the next Node and the previous.

I always check the OK-value if some other malloc had an overflow and overwrited it - then i will exit with an error.

Is my Idea totally bullshit or is it ok?

Edit2:

When I will use now Node instead of void I can store also my location pointer to the node.

```
Node *actual_pointer = sbrk(sizeof(Node));


actual_pointer->checkCorruption_[1] = 'O';
printf("actual_pointer: %p\n", actual_pointer);
printf("actual_O: %c\n", actual_pointer->checkCorruption_[1]);
printf("actual_pointer_before: %p\n", actual_pointer);
actual_pointer = actual_pointer+sizeof(char);
printf("actual_pointer_after: %p\n", actual_pointer);
```

Output:

```
actual_pointer: 0x1ad4000
actual_O: O
actual_pointer_before: 0x1ad4000
actual_pointer_after: 0x1ad4028
```

But now I have some problems with `actual_pointer = actual_pointer+sizeof(char);`. This command should add the size of char to the `actual_pointer` but it increases the pointer with 40 bytes? I don't understand this?

Thanks in Advance,

Philipp

Comment: Even after you fix those trivial compilation errors, you will run into some hard runtime errors, as you will be attempting to store into unaligned memory address. I suggest that you explain exactly what you want to write where (`"OK"`, size, address), as well as what is the `Node` structure. Then, someone here might point out exactly how it can be done **safely**.

Comment: I changed the informations and now I wrote how I would solve this malloc function.

Comment: So just use `Node *actual_pointer` instead of `void *actual_pointer`, and set the fields as you would normally do for any structure (for example, `actual_pointer->size_ = size;`). This should take care of both the compilation errors that you are experiencing **and** the runtime errors that you are likely to experience.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have some other problem or misunderstanding (Edit2). I thought I know C :P

Comment: With `Type* x`, the operation `x = x+5` is equivalent to incrementing the pointer by `5*sizeof(Type)`, and not by `5`. You can increment `actual_pointer` by 1 if you really want, but it would be very wrong (you'll most likely get runtime errors after changing fields in it). Please explain your purpose in performing this operation.

Comment: Oh… now I understand. The `Node *actual_pointer` knows where he has to store the values. I thought I have to move the `actual_pointer` to the next position, for example `size_`. Now everything works as expected and I can try to continue my malloc function. Thank you very much, I hope I don't need anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to store value into a void...

Try replacing the last line with

```
*(unsigned int*)actual_pointer = (unsigned int*)actual_pointer
```

Comment: OP is not "storing value into a void" (he or she are casting properly). The compilation errors are in fact due to the attempt to increment the `void` pointer. And in any case, those compilation errors are the least problem in this case.

Comment: _OP is not "storing value into a void" (he or she are casting properly)._ - This statement is obviously false. The original post has the definition `void *actual_pointer` and the assignment `*actual_pointer = actual_pointer`, so the type of the left hand side is `void`.